# nginx django static files 403 forbidden error permission denied

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, server, ubuntu-16.04

ngnix.conf

```
server_name _;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
             alias /home/megasoft/bots/hisoblovchibot/backend/static/;
        }

        location / {
             include proxy_params;
             proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
```

2023/09/01 10:41:20 [error] 11593#11593: *1 open() "/home/megasoft/bots/hisoblovchibot/backend/static/admin/js/core.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.1.30, server: _, request: "GET /static/admin/js/core.js HTTP/1.1", host: "195.158.26.12:9938"

Comment: I think you need to change permission to root

Comment: Check directory and file permissions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.